# How to customize bibliography to a specific style/format using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber, bibliographystyle

I have been asked to change my bibliography style to something like this:

> T. M. Doe and A. Smith. Classification of molecular devices. *Anal. Chem.*, **10**, 1-8, (2018).

So:
abbreviated first names before last name, article title, abbreviated and italicized journal names, bold volume numbers, page numbers, and year in parentheses.

I am only somewhat familiar with latex and biblatex in general. I've tried looking through the existing styles, and none seem to exactly match. Is there a style that does match? If not, is there a way to customize the format?

Comment: You have tools in biblatex, and the `xpatch` package has commands to patch bib macros or bib drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the [`phys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys) bibliography style and adjust the title, journal and punctuation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend = biber, style = phys]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\adddot\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Rueda_2014,
    author  = {Doe, T M and Smith, A},
    title   = {Classification of molecular devices},
    journal = {Anal. Chem.},
    volume  = {10},
    pages   = {1-8},
    year    = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: References]